# 1 Million TPS with EVM Rollup?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru, evm-rollup

Now that the first alpha version of the EVM rollup is released - I wonder if it is possible to achieve with this EVM rollup also 1 million TPS? Or are there certain limitations in this kernel design that makes it not possible? I know its work in progress with the rollup but is this possible once the evm rollup is more mature?

I imagine one usecase for example a game with many interactions where many users play at once. Instead of waiting for blocktimes confirmation this would allow smooth playing for thousands of users.

This would enable so many things and could bring many users without the gas spikes and congestion on Ethereum network.